# content not visible on website

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've discovered some kind of bug on my website. <strike>I'm using two kinds of menus. One for the front page (.navbar-inverse) and one for all the other pages (.navbar-default).</strike>

The menu on the front page is static and the other one is fixed. It took my a couple of days to find where the problem was but now I saw it. When I was browsing around the site everything looked fine, but when I went back to the front page again, all the content had disappeared and everything was just white.

I tracked the problem down and found out that it has something to do with the .navbar-static-top menu. But I can't find anything weird with the code.

this is my website:

http://dev2015.proformat.se

I've temporarily changed the menu on all the pages to .navbar-static-top so that you guys can see the problem. None of the content is showing up. But the pages are just as long as if there was content beneath the menu.

I use bootstrap with wordpress.

EDIT:

You might have to click around a bit on the site to see the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your issue has nothing to do with Bootstrap's navbar styling.

The style 'overflow: hidden' on #primary is what is causing the content to appear missing. Just remove it and it'll work fine.

[image: Style to remove]

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't even know why that style was there. But that did the trick! Thank you again!